# Something weaker than the Riesz basis

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I have some function $f$, real valued and continuous.
I formed functions $\{f_{m,k}, k \in \mathbb{Z}, m>0\}$ such that that $\mathrm{span}\{f_{m,k}, k \in \mathbb{Z}, m>0\}$ is dense in $L_p(R)$.

Now I would like to constract a Riesz basis from $\{f_{m,k}, k \in \mathbb{Z}, m>0\}$, but unfortunately, my $\{f_{m,k}\}$ does not generate a Riesz basis.

I am wondering if there is some weaker/stronger structure than the Riesz basis, such that $\{f_{m,k}, k \in \mathbb{Z}, m>0\}$ can possibly generate?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe some kind of a [frame](http://www.math.missouri.edu/~pete/pdf/57-FramesBSpaces.pdf)?

Comment: @Leonid Kovalev: Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term you're looking for is probably [Schauder basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis), altough for that you also need some independence properties (as usual with bases).